# Merging 2 data.frames with merge() produce error:Error in sort.list(bx[m$xi])

Tags: r, sorting, merge

I created 2 data frames:

```
x = list("a", "b",1,2)
m1=matrix(x,2,2)
colnames(m1) <- c("gene", "fc")

y = list("A", "B", "C",1,2,3)
m2 = matrix(y,3,2)
colnames(m2) <- c("gene", "fc")

df1 <- as.data.frame(m1)
df2 <- as.data.frame(m2)
```

I try to merge these 2 dataframe using:

```
merged <- merge(df1, df2, by=("gene"))
```

But I got this error:

> Error in sort.list(bx[m$xi]) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'
>   Have you called 'sort' on a list?

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind the error is that in dataframes that you have mentioned, the columns are stored as `list` and not base data types like integer, numeric, character, factor etc.

When one runs this command, one gets some real idea about what's going on.

```
> str(df1)
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ gene:List of 2
  ..$ : chr "a"
  ..$ : chr "b"
 $ fc  :List of 2
  ..$ : num 1
  ..$ : num 2
```

Solution:

1) You can store the dataframes like this:

```
df1 <- data.frame(gene = c('a','b'),fc = c(1,2))

df2 <- data.frame(gene = c('a','b','c'),fc = c(1,2,3))

merge(df1,df2,by='gene')
```

Comment: Is there a way to coerce the list-class of my data to base data?

Comment: Yes. There is a way. But in that case, all the elements will be of only one type. You can go for `unlist()` function

Comment: @ALejandro; one thing to note is that the genes are a different case in your two dataframes, therefore there are no common genes to match. So first coerce both  to lower (or upper case). You can then merge with `df2$gene <- tolower(df2$gene) ; merge(lapply(df1, unlist), lapply(df2, unlist), by="gene", all=TRUE)`. However, I would try and avoid putting your data in such a format in the first place.